# Can't Add System.IdentityModel package/reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, asp.net-identity

Long story short I want to create authentication for my WCF service.

Target framework: .NET 4.5.

I'm following this [User Name Password Validator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354513.aspx).

I'm trying to inherit from UserNamePasswordValidator class but VS2013 keep giving me this error :

My code:

```
 public class UserNamePassValidator : System.IdentityModel.UserNamePasswordValidator
{
}
```

The error i'm getting:

> Error 1 The type or namespace name 'IdentityModel' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I've tried a couple of diffrent ways to solve this: (none of them help me)

1. I've installed Windows Identity Foundation and the WIF SDK.
2. I've add dll manually with this path: `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Windows Identity Foundation\v3.5\    Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll`
3. I try to search for that package in the Nuget Package Manager but nothing come up, only System.IdentityModel.Token (I reference it too but it didn't help).

What am i missing here ? its probably something obvious that I don't see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Target Framework is 4.5, then there is no package to download in order to use WIF. System.IdentityModel is fully integrated to Framework 4.5 and it is the type used by WIF when targeting Framework 4.5 and higher.

Also, you should inherit from this type: System.IdentityModel.Selectors.UserNamePasswordValidator:

```html
public class UserNamePassValidator : System.IdentityModel.Selectors.UserNamePasswordValidator
{
 public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        return;
    }
}​
```

You can refer to the links below:

1- [UserNamePasswordValidator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.selectors.usernamepasswordvalidator(v=vs.110).aspx)

2- [What do I need to build a claims-aware wcf service in VS 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/napegadie_kones_msft_blog/archive/2015/04/03/what-do-i-need-to-build-a-claims-aware-wcf-service-in-vs-2013.aspx)